# Is there fast way to find a parent node of a match to cts:element-value-match()?

Tags: xpath, indexing, xquery, marklogic, query-performance

I am using the `cts:element-value-match()` to find an value in a large set of icd-10 codes (over 70K items).  The results return quickly since we use a string range index.

The structure of the items looks like this:

```
<item>
   <value>E232</value>
   <label>Diabetes insipidus</label>
<item>
```

Here is a sample of how I am calling  `cts:element-value-match()`:

```
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("label"), '*diabetes*', $options)
```

However, `cts:element-value-match()` just returns the value string.  Now I need a fast way to find out the parent node of this value.  The only way I can seem to do this is by using XPath expressions which are extremely slow and compare the string with every label in the document.

```
let $value:= /codes/items/item[label = $label]/value
```

Is there some way to get the parent node from the result string?  If not, is there some function other than `cts:element-value-match()` that I should be using?  Or should I create a field that combines the value/label pairs and just search that field?

Answer (score 1):

XPath is not necessarily slow, but does involve getting the document. It might be possible to leverage caching somehow. It could help to use patterns like `doc('/mycodes.xml')/codes/items/item[label = 'somelabel']/value`, if necessary using `xdmp:value`.

Though, a better approach might be to reconsider how you store your items. If you store each in a separate file, you could use co-occurrences to pull up the values along with their labels.

If there are reasons to not want to touch your codes structure, and you are able to use MarkLogic 9, you could also consider using TDE to build a view in which each item takes a row, and use SQL, or Optic API to query it.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Mads.  I did try your suggestion and used the doc() function and it was still equally slow since it had to do over 70K comparisons for each lookup despite the range index on the label.  We are using ML-9 but not all our environments are upgraded, and the SQL and Optic API seems a bit of an overkill.  I realized I could split each <item> into a separate file and then use cts:word-query(), but there is also an additional 800 byte overhead per file.  I am still looking at building a composite element that concats the two values and build a range index on that element.

Comment: I also pondered about triples, might be worth taking a look at that too. Downside is that there is no `cts:triple-match`, but there are regex and wildcard options in SPARQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why yous start with a value-match vs a range query if you need more than the value back to begin with.

Have you tried scoping the xpath with a searchable expression and using cts:element-value-range-query()

something like:

```
cts:search(doc()/elements/element, cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("label"), '=', '*diabetes*')
```

Returning:

```
<item>
   <value>E232</value>
   <label>Diabetes insipidus</label>
<item>
```

If you had a fragment root on the item element, then this should be extremely efficient. However, I would suggest you consider weighing fragment roots vs re-structuring your data.

You also mention that you considered triples. Triples have a triple-range-query that could have worked.

And going back to my first statement - if the above works, then there may be little value in the range index in the end because you can affect the wild-card on the universal index with an element-word-query, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for your suggestions.  I didn't realize that adding an XPath expression to the end of the first parameter of cts:search would speed up the query.  But it did work as long as I didn't use the unfiltered option!   I also tried using both cts:element-value-match() and cts:word-query() and found that word query was faster.

I also found that adding cts:index-order() sped up the results.

Here is what my final query looks like:

```
let $q := xdmp:get-request-field('q', 'diabetes') let $start := xs:positiveInteger(xdmp:get-request-field('start', '1')) 
let $page-length := xs:positiveInteger(xdmp:get-request-field('start', '10'))
let $end := $start + $page-length - 1

let $results := cts:search(doc('/reference-data/icd-10-codes.xml')/codes/items/item, cts:word-query($q), ("filtered", cts:index-order(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("label")))))[$start to $end]
```

This returns the results to an HTML table view in about 1/10th of a second, which is good enough for my "Demonstration of Value" stage.

I noticed that I had to use a "filtered" option.  The "unfiltered" option seems to ONLY work if the root element is used as the first parameter to the cts:search() function.  So I guess that the full ICD-10 document is still being loaded into the e-node.

If 1/10 of a second is too long in production we can break the file into 70K small files.

Thanks again Mads and David!